# Loading weak cache in typescript

Tags: typescript, cache, weak-references

In Java, I use a [`LoadingCache`](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Population#loading) which offers [weakKeys](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.github.ben-manes.caffeine/caffeine/2.2.0/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/Caffeine.html#weakKeys--) 
and I need something similar in Typescript, so I wrote the following:

```
function loadingWeakCache<K extends object, V>(loader: (k: K) => V) : ((k: K) => V) {
    const cache = new WeakMap<K, V>();
    return function(k: K) : V {
        let v = cache.get(k);
        if (v !== undefined) return v;
        v = loader(k);
        cache.set(k, v);
        return v;
    };
}
```

It seems to work and I'd like it to be reviewed<sup>*</sup>

Unfortunately, I need to cache a two-argument function. My first attempt was

```
function pairLoadingWeakCache<K1 extends object, K2 extends object, V>(loader: (k1: K1, k2: K2) => V) : (k1: K1, k2: K2) => V {
    const cache = new WeakMap<K1, (k2: K2) => V>();
    return function(k1: K1, k2: K2) : V {
        let second = cache.get(k1);
        if (second !== undefined) return second(k2);
        const v = loader(k1, k2);
        second = loadingWeakCache(k => loader(k1, k));
        cache.set(k1, second);
        return second(k2);
    };
}
```

which was wrong as it prevented collecting the second key because of it being referenced from the closure. I'm only presenting it here as it's a smart but broken idea someone could propose. I rewrote it as

```
function pairLoadingWeakCache<K1 extends object, K2 extends object, V>(loader: (k1: K1, k2: K2) => V) : (k1: K1, k2: K2) => V {
    const cache = new WeakMap<K1, WeakMap<K2, V>>();
    return function(k1: K1, k2: K2) : V {
        let second = cache.get(k1);
        if (second === undefined) {
            second = new WeakMap();
            cache.set(k1, second);
        } else {
            const v = second.get(k2);
            if (v !== undefined) return v;
        }
        const v = loader(k1, k2);
        second.set(k2, v);
        return v;
    };
}
```

and I'd like it to be reviewed<sup>*</sup> as well.

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>Just please ignore my single-line conditionals as it's my strongly preferred way.</sub>